# Getting word index by a delimiter in a variable

Tags: bash, shell

Given `line`, `delimiter`, and `word` I want to get the index place of that word in the line based on the delimiter. As simple/short as possible. So for:

```
line="this-is-a-line_with-some.txt" 
delimiter="-" 
word="some"
 
echo <code goes here>
# should come out as 4
```

Of course I can split it with an array, and print the first occurrence of the word with a for loop, as follows:

```
line="this-is-a-line_with-some.txt" 
delimiter="-" 
word="some"

index=0
IFS="$delimiter" read -ra ary <<<"$line"
for i in "${ary[@]}"; do
    if [[ $i == ${word}* ]]; then echo $index ; break ; fi
    index=$((index+1))
done
```

But I'm sure there is a simpler solution.

Comment: `"some" != "some.txt"`.  Do you want to match substrings, or are you treating `.` in a special way?

Comment: @WilliamPursell that is good point, I use `some*` so it doesn't really matter to me

Comment: Reason for short code is that I want to keep my scripts as short/few external calls as possible.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be making this a shell script in the first place. Use a more expressive language.

Comment: Can you use zsh instead of bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **simpler** solution.

Replace delimiter with newline and get line numbers with grep.

```
<<<"$line" tr "$delimiter" '\n' | grep -n "$word" | cut -d: -f1
```

---

Minus 1:

```
<<<"$line" tr "$delimiter" '\n' | grep -n "$word" | cut -d: -f1 | awk '{print $1 - 1}'
# shorter
<<<"$line" tr "$delimiter" '\n' | grep -n "$word" | awk -F: '{print $1-1}'
```

Or really anyway just awk:

```
<<<"$line" awk -v RS="$delimiter" -v word="$word" '$0 ~ word{print NR-1}'
```

Comment: Thanks. making it return index (minus 1) I ran `echo $(($(<<<"$line" tr "$delimiter" '\n' | grep -n "$word" | cut -d: -f1)-1))`

Comment: Ugh, `... | awk '{print $1 - 1}'` looks nicer for me.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding from OP's code and/or comments:

- looking for the **first** occurrence of a `${delimiter}`-delimited field that starts with `${word}`
- location index is 0-based
- if `${word}` is not found we generate **no** output

OP's code can be further reduced by using the array's 0-based index (ie, eliminate the need for the `index` variable):

```
IFS="$delimiter" read -ra ary <<<"$line"
for i in "${!ary[@]}"
do
    [[ "${ary[i]}" == ${word}* ]] && echo "${i}" && break
done

# line="this-is-a-line_with-some.txt"
4

# line="a-some_def-xy-some.pdf"
1
```

**NOTE:** if `${word}` is not found this will generate **no** output

---

A variation on this [paramater substitution solution from superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1024772):

```
newline="${line%%${word}*}"                               # truncate string from 1st occurrence of ${word}

if [[ "${newline}" != "{line}" ]]                         # if strings are different then we found ${word}
then
    IFS="${delimiter}" words_before=( ${newline} )        # break remaining string by "${delimiter}" and
                                                          # store in array words_before[]
    echo "${#words_before[@]}"                            # number of array entries == index of 1st occurrence of ${word}
fi

# line="this-is-a-line_with-some.txt"
4

# line="a-some_def-xy-some.pdf"
1
```

**NOTE:** if `${word}` is not found this will generate **no** output

---

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -F"${delimiter}" -v ptn="${word}" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (index($i,ptn) == 1) {print i-1; exit}}' <<< "${line}"

# line="this-is-a-line_with-some.txt"
4

# line="a-some_def-xy-some.pdf"
1
```

Or using an inline replacement for `ptn/${word}`:

```
awk -F"${delimiter}" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^'"${word}"'/) {print i-1; exit}}' <<< "${line}"

# line="this-is-a-line_with-some.txt"
4

# line="a-some_def-xy-some.pdf"
1
```

**NOTE:** if `${word}` is not found these `awk` scripts will generate **no** output

---

To get ideas for the truly shortest piece of code OP could try posting @ [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), though the really short answers will likely require locating/installing new software (libs and/or binaries)

Answer (score 0):

A solution without loop or external tool :

```
line="$delimiter$line"; lin2="${line%$delimiter$word*}"
if  test "$lin2" != "$line"; then
    IFS="$delimiter" read -ra ary <<<"${lin2#$delimiter}"
    echo ${#ary[@]}
fi
```